# How to connect Python file in XML

Tags: python, xml, br-automation-studio

I want to create a  Button That executes a Python file In b&R Automation Studio. And B&R files written in XML. How can I give the file to execute that

Comment: What PLC and OS are you running your project on?  Will the Python file be on the same PLC?  Is the Python file compiled as an executable?

Comment: I am checking with pc only.No hardware  is used up to now in this project.About python code it is executable

Comment: So, are you running AR000, in Windows and you want to execute a 3rd party .exe file from Visual Components?

Comment: No. For connecting the B and R to DataBase it has to use a python connector. So I want to create a button that connects the  DB in In visual Component

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible.  Maybe contact B&R technical support and ask them.